# Set postfix to relay email from a network interface

Tags: postfix

I'm running postfix on a system that has several external interfaces and several internal interface, and I want postfix to accept email for local delivery from the external interfaces and accept email for relaying from the internal interfaces.

The problem is that the network address of the internal interfaces is dynamic and it changes as the interfaces go up and down (it is a docker server, and the internal interfaces are bridges set up automatically by the docker service when it goes up, according to what non-routeable networks are available at the time of setup).

I know how the internal interfaces are named, so I want to set up postfix with something like:

```
mynetworks = if:docker0 if:docker1
```

but obviously this is not what `mynetworks` does. Is there some way of setting something like this in postfix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No

---

If you read/search the entire page of postfix parameter in [man postconf](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html), then clearly ALL parameters (including `mynetworks`) don't deal with network interface. Postfix only deals with higher layer such as IP address, domain name and others.

The workaround is using script that detect IP address when it changed. This script will write the new IP address to a file. And then set `mynetworks` parameter to that file

```
mynetworks = /path/to/script/output
```

Sample script can be seen at [this page](http://hup.hu/node/102225).

---

Some notes:

- Your script should parse and **do validation of IP address format** before overwriting. Otherwise postfix may misbehaving/stop working.
- Don't forget to execute `postfix reload` when it changed.

Some idea who should to trigger the script

- Crontab
- Docker service (I have no experience about docker and its friends :))
- The OS when network interfaces status becomes up (like [post-up in Debian](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-run-firewall-script-as-soon-as-eth0-interface-brings-up.html) or [if-up.d folder in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41400/how-do-i-make-the-script-to-run-automatically-when-tun0-interface-up-down-events))